# SQL Query to Find Most Effective Data

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to write query for find most effective rows. I have these tables:

```
Sellers
Id   Name
1    Mark
2    Julia
3    Peter

Stocks
 Id   SellerId   ProductCode   StockCount
 1       1         30A            10
 2       2         20A             4
 3       1         20A             2
 4       3         42B             3
```

And there sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe5b1/1/0

My Intent find optimum Seller for stock.

If client want 30A, 20A and 42B products. I need return to "Mark" and "Peter" because Mark have both product(30A and 20A), so not need there Julia.

How can i solve this in sql ?

Comment: Wich RDBMS are you using, MS SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL...? I guess MS SQL Server as SQL Fiddle is using it. Add the needed tag. And the SQL Fiddle link you have added, better edit your question and add it there, so other users looking the question don't need to go through all the comments to be sure they have all the information

Comment: I think the problem here is Ozan wants to find the minimum number of suppliers that can fulfil an order. You would probably want to order the list of suppliers by the total number of items they can supply, coding might be tricky though.

Comment: I think that your problem is more complex then described here. what if both sellers have the same amount of products (but different products?)

Comment: Why you don't need Julia? Peter doesn't have 30A either. You should return only Mark as he has sold 14 stock, then Julia 4 and Peter 3... I don't understand what you want to achieve here.

Comment: @GilPeretz if something like that i need return both of them. Another scenario if mark would have 42B, so peter would disabled.

Comment: In general, how much data is there going to be? (Count of sellers, stocks, desired products)

Comment: @AakashM about 4000 seller and 40000 stock for products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it to work with the help of temporary tables

```
SELECT
  s.SellerId,
  ProductList = STUFF((
                       SELECT ',' + ProductCode FROM Stocks
                        WHERE s.SellerId = Stocks.SellerId
                        ORDER BY ProductCode FOR XML PATH('')
                       )
                      , 1, 1, ''), COUNT(*) AS numberOfProducts
INTO #tmptable
FROM
  Stocks s
WHERE
  s.ProductCode IN ('30A','20A','42B')
  AND s.StockData > 0
GROUP BY s.SellerId;

/*this second temp table is necessary, so we can delete from one of them*/
SELECT * INTO #tmptable2 FROM #tmptable; 

DELETE t1 FROM #tmptable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tmptable2 t2
               WHERE t1.SellerId != t2.SellerId
                 AND t2.ProductList LIKE '%' + t1.ProductList + '%'
                 AND t2.numberOfProducts > t1.numberOfProducts)
;

SELECT Name FROM #tmptable t INNER JOIN Sellers ON t.SellerId = Sellers.Id;
```

**UPDATE:**

Please have a try with static tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tmptable (SellerId int, ProductList nvarchar(max), numberOfProducts int);
```

same for tmpTable2. Then change above code to

```
INSERT INTO tmpTable
SELECT
  s.SellerId,
  ProductList = STUFF((
                       SELECT ',' + ProductCode FROM Stocks
                        WHERE s.SellerId = Stocks.SellerId
                        ORDER BY ProductCode FOR XML PATH('')
                       )
                      , 1, 1, ''), COUNT(*) AS numberOfProducts
FROM
  Stocks s
WHERE
  s.ProductCode IN ('30A','20A','42B')
  AND s.StockData > 0
GROUP BY s.SellerId;

INSERT INTO tmpTable2 SELECT * FROM tmpTable;

DELETE t1 FROM tmptable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tmptable2 t2
               WHERE t1.SellerId != t2.SellerId
                 AND t2.ProductList LIKE '%' + t1.ProductList + '%'
                 AND t2.numberOfProducts > t1.numberOfProducts)
;

SELECT * FROM tmpTable;
DROP TABLE tmpTable, tmpTable2;
```

Comment: One question, like query doesnt work true in real data. it return all products, so query cant delete exists from temptable in real data, our productList value sometimes too long for example 1000 character length, so is it reason or not for your opinion ?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the problem. Do you get an error saying something like the temporary table is too big to be a temporary table? If yes, remove the `#` in front of the temp table name and drop the tables when you don't need them anymore.

Comment: Your code run well on sqlfiddle. When I run your query in real database, it doesnt work as my wishes. So I look your query and I realize that "AND t2.ProductList LIKE '%' + t1.ProductList + '%'" code couldn't find and exists query can't delete from #tmptable so all products listed with numberOfProducts column. ProductList string length is 1000 character in some rows. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Thanks but i tried that it didnt fix problem. My last comment i tried to explain problem. Is there any limitation for like clause ?

Comment: I don't know, to be honest. I suggest that you ask why this query doesn't work over at dba.stackexchange.com It's a partner site of stackoverflow which is more database oriented. Sorry I can't help.

Answer (score -2):

I think this might be what you are looking for?

```
Select name,sum(stockdata) as stockdata from sellers s1 join Stocks s2 on s1.id=s2.sellerid
where ProductCode in ('30A','20A','42B')
group by name
order by sum(stockdata) desc
```

I hope it helps.

if you only want the top 2 ppl. You write

```
Select top 2 name,sum(stockdata) as stockdata from sellers s1 join Stocks s2 on s1.id=s2.sellerid
where ProductCode in ('30A','20A','42B')
group by name
order by sum(stockdata) desc
```

I think this is what you are looking for, since how I see it, you want to select the two people who has the highest stockdata?

Comment: No, this is not, what he's looking for. He just doesn't want Julia because Mark has her product plus another one, therefore Mark is more "effective".

Comment: ah, hehe sorry about that :)